# Hide phone number from the dialler in android programatically

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am having task where i want to  hide the number when we make call.
For example:-
User A have application were there is name appear on the screen for some user(Example user B).
Now when user click on the name the call will occurs to user B.(Phone number is already there in the server).

Now when we make the call is should be such that the dialler should show only the name of the user.i.e USERB and not his number on the dialler.
Such that there is no way user can able to find out the number of user B.

please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some of the code you are using?

Comment: @Gautham thanks for the quick reply.. I got this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534059/android-custom-dialler-on-tapping-phone-number-links?rq=1 and i use this..but still I am not able to hide the number.

Comment: Any error occurs ??? Or nothing happening ??

Comment: Make your question bit finer. Its very hard to understand it.

Comment: If you are controlling the text display for the number, u can use the setvisibility(false) functionality to hide the phone number. I need to know more to help you further.

Comment: This does not sound like behavior the system should support.  Note the information you seek to hide will probably be on the customer's itemized bill, too.

Comment: @Gautham how do i set the visibity for the number in the native dialler of the phone?.

Comment: @Andru There is dialler which appear when we make a call.. so what i want is to customise that dialer in such a way that the number get hidden.

Comment: @PiyushGupta nothing happen.I had write this in my manifest file.. but nothing happen

Comment: @Gautham I am not accessing camera application.I just want to create custom dialler like skype but using mobile provided.skype is using voip provider

Comment: Sorry I meant to say native caller app